# how to render django location field by id?

Tags: javascript, django, leaflet, geojson, geodjango

i have a model in django like this :

```
...

class Post (models.Model)

 title = models.CharField(max_length=120)

 location = models.PointField(srid=4326, null=True, blank=True)
 objects = GeoManager()

 def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

 def get_absoulute_url(self):
     return reverse("post_map", kwargs={
    'id':self.id

    })
...
```

and i want to render location place by id like this:

```
...

path('post-map/<id>/post_map/',post_map,name='post_map')
path('post-map/<id>/post_page/',post_page,name='post_map')
path('post-map/<id>/home_page/',home_page,name='post_map')
...
```

an view.py:

```
...

def post_map(request,id):
     #i can render Post.objects.all() but i cant render this:
     name = serialize('geojson',get_objects_or_404(Post, id=id)
     return HttpResponse(name,content_type='json')


def home_page(request):
    return render(request,'home_page.html')


def post_page(request,id):

    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)

    context = {
       'post':post,
    }
    return render(request,'post-pagepltest.html',context)
...
```

and this is a part of code in post_page.html

```
<div class="w-100 map border ">

<i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt  float-right"></i>
<a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}home_page">
<span class="badge badge-pill float-left mr-auto badge-danger "> map- 
 location </span>
</a>
</div>
```

and home_page.html is:

```
...

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% load static %}
{% load leaflet_tags %}

<head>
    {% leaflet_js %}
    {% leaflet_css %}
    <title> home </title>


    <style type="text/css">
      #gis {width:80%; height:700px;}
    </style>

    <script type ="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js2/leaflet.ajax.js' %}" ></script>




</head>
<body>
<h3>we are heroes!!<h3>
<br>

<script type="text/javascript">


  function our_layers(map,options){
    var datasets = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'post_map' %}",{

    });
    datasets.addTo(map);
  }



</script>
{% leaflet_map "gis" callback="window.our_layers" %}
</body>
</html>
```

but i cant render it by id ,is there any way to solve this problem?
i can save data and also can render all location to view map functiom with 
  name = serialize('geojson',get_objects_or_404(Post, id=id)
but i cant render in by each id for each post 
how can i render post by id to show epecific location like this ?

name = serialize('geojson',get_objects_or_404(Post, id=id)

Comment: I don't understand what's the exact problem. What error are you getting when going to which url? Please describe what you do (e.g. "I type '/post-map/3/map/' in my browser address bar"), what you expect to see ("I expect to see one Post location displayed on the map") and what you actually see ("but I'm getting an error, here's the full stack trace of the error: ...").

Comment: You urls.py are wrong, because you have two urls with the same name. That's not allowed. Also, your home url is wrong, because it takes an id (`/post-map/<id>/index`), but your view does not accept an id (`def home_page(request):`). And the first url points to a view that you're not showing, `post_map`.

Comment: hi , urls.py with same name is true becaus i tested it before by passing get_absolut_url in model and render it like this in template: <a href={{ " post.get_absolut_url" }}map> link</a>  ,thats working but in this case i want when user click on link see the location of each post on map , also i can render all of post location by :Post.objects.all() in map view but i cant render it by specific id..

Comment: Having the same name doesn't raise an error, Django will just use the first name it encounters, which by chance is the correct one for get_absolute_url. Your home page url will never be found by that same name if you try to use reverse.

Comment: Second, your question is not clear. "When user click on link see location of each post". Which link? Where's the link in your home page? I assume it would be `{% url 'post_map' post.id %}` if you have a `post` in your home page, e.g. `{% for post in posts %}` if you're looping through all the posts somewhere. That would send a request to your `post_map` view (which you're not showing, I only see a `map` view) and that view would have an id, so it could return the specific post. But if you already have all the posts in your home page, then `post.location` is the location.

Comment: ok , you right , i forgot input my another template that has link , but my link is : {% url 'post_map' post.id %}, so when i click on it , i render it to home_page.html

Comment: What do you mean "choose another name"???? Where do I see a "name" in your code? Where do you choose? How do you choose? You really need to learn [ask] a question. Nothing in your question shows how you display the posts in the first place (your home page is just a template with no data). And the answer below already shows you how to fix your view and call it.

Comment: my mean is another name for url not "name" and my  question is clear .i want see location of each post in template by leaflet map if you have any solution with any models and any view and any template that you know write it plz

Comment: Your question is totally unclear to me.  You say "when I click on it" but there are not posts in the home page because you don't pass them to the context of your template so nothing to click. If your home_page view had something like `posts = Post.objects.all()` and `render(request, "home_page.html", {'posts': posts})`, and then in your template you have `{% for post in posts %} <a href="{% 'post_map' post.id %}">click here</a> {% endfor %}` then I would maybe understand, but your template has no links to click and no posts to loop through. So I don't understand what you want.

Comment: ok im so sorry i edited my post , you were right plz check it and if its not clear yet tell me

Comment: Why do you have “home_page” in the href of your link?

Comment: beacus my ulr is post-map/<id>/home_page/ so after get_absolut_url we have home_page and this work i tested it before

Comment: But get_absolute_url returns /post-map/id/post_map/ so adding home_page to it can’t give what you want. Look in your browser html source.

Comment: i render this url path('post-map/<id>/post_map/',post_map,name='post_map')  with :                 function our_layers(map,options){
    var datasets = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'post_map' %}",{

    });
    datasets.addTo(map);
  }                                                                                                                           in home_page.html

Comment: and aslo render this url : path('post-map/<id>/home_page/',home_page,name='post_map')  with <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}home_page">
<span class="badge badge-pill float-left mr-auto badge-danger "> map- 
 location </span>
</a>

Comment: No you don't. In both cases your urls in the template don't match your url patterns. First of all, please give your urls different names, as I told in my first comment. You cannot have two urls with the same name!!! To fetch url "post-map/<id>/post_map/" you need to do `{% url 'post_map' some_id %}`, without id it will give you an error. To fetch url "post-map/<id>/home_page" you can't use {% url %} because the name is conflicting with the previous one and you can't use `get_absolute_url` because that gives you the first one. See how what you're saying doesn't make sense?

Comment: {% url 'post_map' some_id %} doesnt work i tested it with another url name     ,i steel dont know what to do with post_page in view could you plz writ exaple function views.py with its url ?

Comment: i did every think you said but it steel not working , does it work for you? did you test it ? if you find solution plz tell me becuse i really need it thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url need to id parameters, so you should do like this;

```
{% url 'post_map' id=1 %}
```

You can use it to get by id.

---

Also your view should pass a context to the template that's rendered:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def map (request,id):
 name = serialize('geojson',get_objects_or_404(Post, id=id)
 # you can call {{name}}
 return render(request, "home_page.html", {'name':name})
```

Comment: thanks but this is not working yet i want to show location of each post when users click on it